# Tkinter Notebook how to add right and left arrows for scrolling all Tabs

Tags: python, tkinter

Tkinter Notebook how to make Tabs show full name and add right and left arrows for scrolling all Tabs

As picture shown, the tab name is not fully displayed. And I need to add left and right arrows, top display.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def add(comp, title):
    frame1 = ttk.Frame(comp, width=1400, height=280)
    frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    notebook.add(frame1, text=title)
# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')
root.title('Notebook Demo')

# create a notebook
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)

for i in range(10):
    add(notebook, f"Tab {i} XXXX")

root.mainloop()
```

[image]